# why wouldn't a java awt app release focus, on osx, with a custom protocol handler?

Tags: java, macos, awt

After launching a simple java awt app on OSX, no other applications can take focus. Clicking on other apps has no effect. It's impossible to enter text into any app except the awt app, until it exits.

This happens *only* when launching via a custom protocol handler, like `open foobar:`, or clicking on a `foobar:` link from a browser. When launching via double-click, or `open /Applications/My.app`, or `java -jar`, it works fine: other apps can take focus.

What part of the system is controlling focus? LaunchServices? java? And what's different about opening via a custom protocol?